# Upgrading packages through Terminal and knowing when a restart is then needed

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates, 14.10

When I run the application `Software Updater` and I install some updates which need a restart of my computer, it tells me that I need to restart.

But when running this command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It is not clear whether or not the packages which you have upgraded require a restart of the computer once they have finished upgrading. So I was wondering if and how you would check if any of the packages which you have upgraded need a restart of your computer?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Usually the icon in the top right, that you'd use to select the shutdown options, turns red when a restart is required. Also, AFAIK you should only need to restart after updating if the kernel has been modified/upgraded.

Comment: @amanthethy Nope, I have never seen that. And I have upgraded many packages which I know need a restart.

Comment: @Toroidal Maybe they removed it :s Used to look just like this. http://www.opensourceforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Ubuntu1204-22-reboot-update.png

Comment: @amanthethy: Well I assume that they got rid of it for I have never seen it before. Although I wonder why they removed it, for it was a rather useful feature.

Comment: I have made a suggestion here for a better way of handling this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1411637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a package wants you to reboot it creates the file `/var/run/reboot-required`.